# two types of constructors with a single template?

Tags: c++, templates

Probably the question title is nonsensical so let me explain what I am trying to do! I have this template class

```
template <class TBase>
class A : public TBase
{
public:
  A() { /* some initialization */ }
};
```

the "inner" class can be either of these 2:

```
class B1
{// no constructor required
};

class B2
{ 
public:
  B2(int& m) : m_mode(m) { }
protected:
  int& m_mode;
};
```

Note that B2 has a reference member variable so it needs a constructor initialization list. It is easy to create an instance of `A<B1>` but how does one make `A<B2>`? I could obviously drop the reference and use a pointer, but I wonder if this puzzle has an easy solution I cannot see?

thanks

Comment: Is `A<B2>` default constructable, or does the `int&` come from outside?

Answer (score 1):

All sub-object must be constructible in the manner selected by your derived constructor, and all must have an accessible destructor.

Any sub-object neither explicitly constructed in the ctor-init-list nor by an in-class initializer will be default-constructed.
(Which is forbidden for references.)

Thus, your `B2` needs to gain a default-ctor, or `A` needs to call the existing one in the described manner.
Because `A` is a `template`, specializing it `B2` is an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could specialize `A`:

```
class B1
{
};

class B2
{
public:
  B2 (int& m) : m_mode (m) {}; 
protected:
  int& m_mode;
};

template <class TBase> class A;

template <> class A <B2> : public B2
{
public:
  A(int& m) : B2 (m) {}
};

template <class TBase> class A : public TBase
{
public:
  A() : TBase () {}; 
};

int main()
{
  int x = 42; 

  A <B1> a1; 
  A <B2> a2 (x);
}
```

Comment: in that case we have the template A "defined" twice with lots of code duplication... not nice!

Comment: @nikos:  You're right -- that's why I did something here I almost never do:  I posted two answers.

Comment: @nikos: There's trivial ways to eliminate virtually all of the code duplication, via inheritance from `AImpl<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my C++11 approach, using variadic templates

```
template <typename TBase, typename... Args>
class A : public TBase
{
public:
  A(Args... args): TBase(args...) { /* some initialization */ }
};

class B1
{// no constructor required
};

class B2
{ 
public:
  B2(int& m) : m_mode(m) { }
protected:
  int& m_mode;
};

int main()
{
    A<B1> fooA;
    int n = 10;

    A<B2, int> fooB(n);
}
```

Comment: Consider me a fan of this approach.

Comment: Variadic templates are a really nice addition to C++, I am a fan also

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, depending on how complex the base classes are and how many specializations you would end up needing, I'd prefer to use a class factory:

```
class B1
{
};

class B2
{
public:
  B2 (int& m) : m_mode (m) {};
protected:
  int& m_mode;
};

class B1Factory
{
public:
  B1 Make () const { return B1(); }
};

class B2Factory
{
public:
  B2Factory (int& ref) : mRef (ref) {};
  B2 Make () const { return B2 (mRef); }
private:
  int& mRef;
};

template <class TBase> class A : public TBase
{
public:
  template <typename Factory> A (const Factory& fac)
  :
    TBase (fac.Make())
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  int x = 42;

  A <B1> a1 (B1Factory());
  A <B2> a2 (B2Factory (x));
}
```

Note here there is no need to specialize `A`, meaning code duplication is reduced.  This is good for DRY code.

Comment: I lost you there! This is beyond me (I'm using VS6 :). I think I'll just drop the reference and use a pointer so both B1 and B2 can do the default constructor. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: @nikos:  Try it out.  I gave you a fully-compilable sample.

Comment: @nikos:  I think VS6 should be able to handle this.  In any case, you really, **really** should get off of VS6.  It hasn't been supported in years, and it was a terrible compiler even when it was supported.

Answer (score 0):

No big deal, B can have two constructors:

```
template <class TBase>
class A : public TBase
{
public:
  A() { /* some initialization */ }
  A(int & ri) : TBase(ri) { /* some other initialization */ }
};
```

Unused members just aren't instantiated. Of course, you get a compile time error if you use the wrong ctor.

Comment: I asked for a simple solution and I guess this is it (if it compiles without modifying B2 class). But it isn't pretty! So thanks but I'll have to change my structures and avoid such silly workarounds :)